# Where the implement of Machine Learning / Deep Learning / NLP in web development or web application?

Tags: php, web, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am a newbie web application developer. Already build some application. Recently i see,  Machine Learning / Deep Learning / NLP have more value. I wanna know How I can apply Machine Learning / Deep Learning / NLP on web application ? Where the implement of those in Web Application ? And what's the best language for Machine Learning / Deep Learning / NLP ? (I'm a php dev)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use machine learning and deep learning in your application, I think is providing some web services and call them from client side. For example if you want to create a website for OCR or object detection, you can build a model using **Tensorflow** in **Python**, **train** it and at last **deploy** it as a **Flask** or **Cherrypy** service. Then you can call these services from client side.

Another way is to use **tensorflow.js**. Using it you can use a trained deep learning model on client side without providing a web service at all. In this way, the model is downloaded at client side and the output of the model is calculated using the client's resources.

All of All **Tensorflow** as a back-end and **Python** as a programming language are good starting points to be getting involved with deep learning.